# 4 external load form.html in a div on click on the radio with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, load

I would like to load pages 4 through 4 radio button with AJAX.
    example: 
    Radio A load pageA.html
    Radio B load pageB.html 
    Radio C load pageC.html 
    Radio D load pageD.html 
    And if the user refreshes the page I'd like to remain the last selection you made. 
    I'm new with AJAX. 
    The first Radio "A" office perfectly pageA.html. From here on, I have no idea how to load the other pages if you are selected.

```
How can I improve my script? 

Thanks in advance
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>


        Radio A <input id="button" type="radio" name="button" value=""/>
        Radio B <input id="button" type="radio" name="button" value=""/>
        Radio C <input id="button" type="radio" name="button" value=""/>
        Radio D <input id="button" type="radio" name="button" value=""/>

        <div id="content"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My AJAX code**

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'pageA.html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You cannot have duplicate id's in an HTML page or you'll get wonky results.

Comment: You're right, copied and pasted without changing the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the id to the page name then you can shorten your code like this -

HTML

```
Radio A <input id="pageA" type="radio" name="button" value=""/>
Radio B <input id="pageB" type="radio" name="button" value=""/>
Radio C <input id="pageC" type="radio" name="button" value=""/>
Radio D <input id="pageD" type="radio" name="button" value=""/>
```

jQuery

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    var pageName = this.id;
    $('#content').load(pageName + '.html');
});
```

In addition you could give each button a class, then use that in your selector. Either way keeps you from having to repeat code.

Comment: +1.. this is probably a better answer than mine, although I would use CSS classes rather than any radio buttons on the page. If the page changes later (more radio buttons with different functionality) you risk stuff breaking.

Comment: I would use classes too, because of changes that you have anticipated.

Comment: Thank you a few lines that do their job. 
If the user refreshes the page? How can I keep the selected radio? thanks Jay Blanchard

Answer (score 1):

Your radio buttons shouldn't have the same ID.. they should be unique. I'd use jQuery `load()` methods like so as it just always seems a lot cleaner/neater to me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>

        Radio A <input id="button1" type="radio" name="button" value=""/>
        Radio B <input id="button2" type="radio" name="button" value=""/>
        Radio C <input id="button3" type="radio" name="button" value=""/>
        Radio D <input id="button4" type="radio" name="button" value=""/>

        <div id="content"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Then use [jQuery load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#button1').click(function() {
      $("#content").load("pageA.html");
    });

    $('#button2').click(function() {
       $("#content").load("pageB.html");
    });

    $('#button3').click(function() {
       $("#content").load("pageC.html");
    });

    $('#button4').click(function() {
       $("#content").load("pageD.html");
    });
});
```

Comment: netbeans gives me a syntax error, maybe we want the braces to close the function.